# Display html when data is loaded?

Tags: jquery, html

On my page I display lot of data in table, but the UI issue I face currently is that table header is displayed prior to data rendered on the screen, and it look odd.
Can anyone please provide solution to load html and data simultaneously.
some example will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hide the table, and then call `show()` after populating it.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
body {
  display: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("body").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: But in my case the Page is already loaded and there is a Expand/Collapse functionality where I load the table on click of expand.

Comment: Can't help it, unless we can see your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below using jquery:

In css->

```
body{
  display:none;
}
```

in javascript

```
$(document).ready(function({

  $("body").show();

});
```